# CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'content_schedule_block0'

Tags: magento-2.1, product, import

I got this error on product details page.

Added product using **CSV import**.

> 1 exception(s): Exception  0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found
>   with ID 'content_schedule_block0'.
>
> Exception  0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID
>   'content_schedule_block0'.  0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to reindex.
Run below command:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Issue solved.